# Setting the Chef log level in knife ec2 when creating a server

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm looking for the correct way to set chef-client's log level when creating a server using knife ec2.

My initial thought was setting the log level configuration in my knife.rb file like this:

```
log_level                :debug
```

This didn't result in any visible change in the log level.

I also tried turning on the -VV option in knife ec2, but that just results in verbose output from knife ec2 itself.

When I run chef-client directly after logging onto the server, I can get debug information with no problems using:

```
sudo chef-client -l debug
```

That would be sufficient, but I'm investigating an underlying problem that only occurs on the initial server bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the default bootstrap templates always set the default `:auto` log level to the node. There is at least [one ticket](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3610) that seems to be related.

So your only option now is to create your own bootstrap template that adds `log_level :debug` to */etc/chef/client.rb*. You can copy and modify e.g. the default "[chef-full](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb)" template and then pass it as a parameter to knife.

Comment: I ended up working around the problem in a manner very similar to what you're describing, but used a bash script instead of ruby. I bootstrapped the node without run_lists assigned, assigned the run_lists to the node, then ssh'd into the node to execute chef_client with my own debug level.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple hack/work-around that I discovered to control the log level.  In `knife.rb`, include
a line like the following, for example:

```
chef_client_path 'chef-client -l debug'
```

You can see why this works by looking at
[this line](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/11.6.0/lib/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb#L90)
of the Chef source code.  I confirmed that this works in Chef 11.6.
It may work in other versions.